# Mapping Class with multiple Sitecore templates in [SitecoreType()] Attribute

Tags: glass-mapper

I have to map a class with more than one template in GlassMapper. My code is like below.

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{6173F07E-BC5B-4409-A75A-DF1B0D117C41}", AutoMap = true, EnforceTemplateGlass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.SitecoreEnforceTemplate.Template)] 

public class ResourceListings : MSEntity{
 public virtual ID Id { get; set; }
        [SitecoreField("Title")]
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to pass more than one Template Id using pipe like

`[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{6173F07E-BC5B-4409-A75A-DF1B0D117C41}|{3175F07E-BC5B-5409-A75A-CF1B0b117C41}"`,

in above attribute but it throws error.
Is there a way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my knowledge there is no method to achieve your functionality in this way, only way is to use the inheritance by creating multiple class/interface. Since C# doesn't support multiple inheritance in class but you can achieve this using interface. I have never use multilevel inheritance for this but I guess that is also an option for this.

An example of interface, if I have a content page that inherits my IPageTitles template and an IMetadata template then my Content interface can inherit both:

```
public interface Content : IPageTitles, IMetadata{
}
```

and each Interface will have its own [SitecoreType()] Attribute.

An alternative is to use a single class model. The model contains just the properties we need to render. The model is also responsible for retrieving the ancestor items removing the need for any additional code.